# How to determine an element of collection A and other element of collection B are equal using spring webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm study spring-flux, and want to determine an element of collection A and other element of collection B are equal.

collection A: `List<GrantedAuthority>`, and collection B: `HashSet<SecurityConfig>`

Class SecurityConfig has a method `getAttribute`, and Class GrantedAuthority has a method `getAuthority`

using `a.getAuthority().equals(b.getAttribute())` to judge.

please help me, thanks

Comment: If you are working on Spring Webflux, you should be talking about 'Flux' (https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) and not a 'Collection'. If you have collections, then the way of finding whether an element in A is also present in B doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
        Flux
            .zip(Flux.fromIterable(first), Flux.fromIterable(second), (s, s2) -> {
                if (s.equals(s2))//if statement
                    return true;
                return false;
            })
            .flatMap(aBoolean -> aBoolean ? Flux.empty() : Flux.just(aBoolean))
            .collectList()
            .map(booleans -> false)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(true));
```